# Converter uma stream para string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, imap

Estou pegando emails da caixa de entrada de uma conta que criei para testes, estou buscando eles com o [node-imap](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap) e fazendo o parse deles com o [MailParser](https://nodemailer.com/extras/mailparser/) e estou conseguindo recuperar a maior parte das informações que necessito, exceto o texto do email, pois o mesmo se encontra em formato de stream e não sei como transformar ele em uma string para poder enviar para o cliente.

Já estou lendo a documentação do Node.JS para descobrir como faço isso, assim como também estou lendo a documentação do MailParser, porém ainda não achei exatamente o que preciso, agradeço se alguém puder me ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se o retorno da Stream for um buffer você pode fazer algo mais ou menos assim:

```
let string = ''

stream.on('readable',function(buffer){
  let part = buffer.read().toString()
  string += part
  console.log('Stream em string: ' + part)
})

stream.on('end',function(){
 console.log('String final ' + string)
})
```